# Android SimpleCardStackAdapter - get adapter item info and like-dislike button

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I m using [this](https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards) framework for my application.

So I have to button for like and dislike, my code is like that :

```
public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        url = "http://22.11.23.14/";
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            r = getResources();
            String hakki;
            adapter = new SimpleCardStackAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            // Getting JSON Array
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                    final JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String name = c.getString(username);
                    String email = c.getString(text);
                    String image1 = c.getString(imageUrl);
                    String msgId = c.getString(postId);

                    // adapter.add(new CardModel(name, email, image1));
                    card = new CardModel(name, email, image1);

                    //Set JSON Data in TextView
                    Log.i("image1image1image1image1", image1);

                    // CardModel cardModel = new CardModel(" cardModel", " CardModel", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture1));

                    card.setOnClickListener(new CardModel.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnClickListener() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I am pressing the card");
                        }
                    });

                    card.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLike() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I dislike the card");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDislike() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I like the card");
                            new sendsendsendMethod().execute(sharedToken, "msgId");
                        }

                    });

                    adapter.add(card);
                    mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**1.** I want to get adapter Item info. At this line :

String msgId = c.getString(postId);

I m getting postId for every post. How Can I call this msgId every click? Do I need add to adapter? If I add the adapter How can I call adapter item info?

**2.** I have two button outside this adapter, one of for like, another one for dislike. How Can I call like/dislike for active item?

I hope I can explain myself. I m trying almost last 3 days with this problem. Actually I cant...

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: yes I tried for make. I implement onclicklistener and use adapterview onclicklistener but its not working. I will try anything I can, after I create this topic.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: No I didnt findy anything.